# How do i make this textbox update in real time

Tags: vb.net, basic

Basically i want one textbox to do this:

```
TextBox5.Text = TextBox4.Text / TextBox2.Text
```

It works but if i don't try to input something to the textbox it doesn't update. How do i ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. Please provide a more detailed explanation. For starters, you refer to three different `TextBoxes` in your code so saying "the textbox" is rather ambiguous. Edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: TextBox.Text is a string, so what do you expect string / string to yield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle both TextBox_TextChanged events, and try to parse the strings as doubles. If both succeed, then do the math and update the TextBox.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    doMath()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
    doMath()
End Sub

Private Sub doMath()
    Dim tb2 As Double, tb4 As Double
    If Double.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, tb2) AndAlso Double.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, tb4) Then
        TextBox5.Text = (tb4 / tb2).ToString()
    Else
        TextBox5.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

The TextBox will be updated immediately with the quotient when both other TextBoxes are valid doubles.

Remember not to try to do math using strings. You may want to put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file so the compiler tells you you can't do math with strings like this `TextBox4.Text / TextBox2.Text`